# jQuery read title with $.get page

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I would like to get the title witch is included in a other page (on same domain).

On the moment, the following code isn't working:

```
$.get("/example.html", function(html){
    alert($(html).attr('title'));
});
```

Content of the `example.html` page is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>foo</title>
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` at this context to filter out the `title` tag,

```
alert($(html).filter("title").text());
```

And use `.text()` to extract its text content.